# Which is the best practice for extracting value from object?

Tags: c#, reflection

Which is the best practice for extracting property from object ,so that we can take its value?

We have the following code structure:

```
public List<Group> Activities { get; set; }
```

In Group we have:

```
public List<Span> Spans { get; set; }
```

In Span class we have:

```
public object Activity { get; set; }
```

In method I have the following loop that I want to take from object Activity property Id from TV:

```
foreach (var activity in result.Activities)
        {
            if (activity.Spans != null)
            {
                foreach (var span in activity.Spans)
                {
                    if (span.Activity != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof(Spans).GetProperties())
                        {
                            if (propertyInfo.Name == "Activity")
                            {
                             //take value from activity
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In span.Activity we have : { Time = 123, EndTime = 123, Points = [ -48, -49 ], PointsStart = [ 0, -2, ], **TV** = [ { "time": "123", **"Id": 7**, "TitleId": 5 } ] }

I need to take from TV the Id property value and add it later to a list.
Which is the best practice to do it and how?

Comment: What is the actual type of `Activity` ? Can it be different types? What would you do if it is a type without an id-parameter?

Comment: What would you do if it is a type without an id-parameter?
- I need to check if it contains TV and then take value id if not I will continue to next that has TV and ID.
Value of Activity is object as provided ,not changable properties.
The main idea here is to extact all TV Ids from list and Distinct the values to have unique ids in one new list.

Comment: This does answer the question "What is the actual (C#) type of Activity"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be the best practise but you can use reflection.

You can use the [EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Bcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Bcl) nuget package that contains a `GetPropertyValue()` extension method that uses reflection:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Bcl;

// Get all id values
var ids =
    result
        .Activities
        .SelectMany(activity => activity.Spans)
        .Where(spans => spans != null)
        .Select(span => span.Activity)
        .Where(activity => activity != null)
        .Select(
            activity =>
            {
                object tv = activity.GetPropertyValue("TV");

                object rawId = null;

                if (tv is IEnumerable e)
                {
                    rawId = e.Cast<object>().FirstOrDefault()?.GetPropertyValue("Id");
                }

                return rawId is int id ? (int?)id : (int?)null;
            }
        )
        .Where(id => id != null)
        .Cast<int>()
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since Activity inside span is an **unknown** and the object type is **unknown**, we'll have to use something like **REGEX** to match our values.

Here's something that works perfectly.

```
    var regexPatternToGetIdAndNumber = "\"([Id]+?)\"\\s*:\\s*\\d+";
    var regexPatternToGetNumber = "\\d+";

    foreach (var activity in activities.Where(a => a.Spans != null))
    {
        foreach (var span in activity.Spans)
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in span.GetType()
                                            .GetProperties()
                                            .Where(property => property.Name == "Activity"))//Get Properties of Span Names "Activity" 
            {
                var stringValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(span)?.ToString();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue))
                {
                    continue; //If Value is empty, Skip it and continue
                }


                var idAndValueString = Regex.Match(stringValue, regexPatternToGetIdAndNumber).ToString(); //Returns "Id": 7

                var idValue = Regex.Match(idAndValueString, regexPatternToGetNumber).ToString(); //Returns 7;
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Yes, that works too ,but I don't know if Regex is good practice at this case. 
Thank you!

Comment: @Radost: The object type is mostly unknown, might or not be null, but we know this `{"Id": 7}` exists. Perfect scenario for a regex match.

Comment: Is the regex pattern slower than the one with reflection from performance perspective? Because I think that regex is usually slower than it, correct me if I am wrong? Thanks!